# Oro Platform Error

Tags: symfony, orocrm

I am trying to generate a new bundle for the OroCRM (Symfony2), but when I am trying to run the following

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

this error occur

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getProperties() on null in  /var/www/platform-application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaValidator.php on line 239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sudo php app/console cache:clear
```

or this:

```
sudo php app/console cache:clear --force
```